# Set trigger time of periods in Zabbix

Tags: triggers, zabbix

I have a host that I monitor in 08:00-20:00 and trigger which acts when no ping.
Sometimes a host can be switched off in period of 20:00-08:00. I want in this situation dont't to trigger that act till 10:00 next day. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `time()` [trigger function](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/appendix/triggers/functions). Appending this to the existing function should work (replace `...` with the reference to the same item as already in the expression):

```
and time(...) > 080000 and time(...) < 200000
```

Note that this will make the trigger ignore the time period outside of the bounds, so it will fire at 08:00 only if the problem condition still persists. Not sure how 10:00 fits in your original description.

Comment: that fucntion will generate action two times if host was switched off before 20:00

Comment: Could you please clarify what and how would happen two times?

Comment: if host was switched off in 19:00 it will triggered. In period of 20:00-08:00 it will be removed from problems and will appear againg in 08:00 next day. Every time it will trigger. Or i'm not right?

Comment: Indeed - was not thinking of situations where it would be normal for a system to be down for extended periods of time. In that case why not use the built-in maintenance?

Comment: It is a specific host and can be monitored only by ping:)

Comment: Even more, the maintenance should be the solution then.

Answer (score 1):

On newer versions of Zabbix you can set Working hours for items, so the collect just will happens in a specific range..

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.0/manual/appendix/time_period